# Resuming a pthread using cpp

Tags: c++, pthreads, resume

I am writing a program in which I have a daemon thread that runs in the background as long as the main thread is running. When the main thread ends I want to terminate the daemon thread, so I tried two methods:

1. if I use pthread_kill I have a memory leak even when I initialized it as detachable (there's no need to ever join this thread)
2. Since this didn't work, I thought of running the daemon thread in a loop as long as the global `bool _daemonRun` is true.  Before the main thread terminates I set `_daemonRun` to false and then in the daemon I use `pthread_exit(NULL)` outside the loop. Problem is - how do I resume the thread? Using conditional variable seems like a mess because I don't want the thread to wait...

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: When you only want to kill the thread when the process ends, I dont get what you mean by resuming it

Comment: 'When the process ends I want to terminate the thread' - is there any overriding reason to do this explicitly? If not, just end the process and let the OS clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that, you do care about the daemon thread properly releasing its resources (e.g., memory) before the main thread exists. Therefore, creating it as a detached thread seems wrong to me, since that would indicate that you do not care when/if that thread exits.

Therefore, I suggest the following. Create the daemon thread as a normal thread. Then, before the main thread exists, set `_daemonRun` to `false`. Finally, join() the daemon thread.